# Kendo-datetime is throwing error in angular

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

<kendo-datetimepicker [formControlName]="name" [value]="datetimeValue">

I get below error and value is not binding to the control. I have implemented similarly as shown in the url
**FormlyDateTimePickerComponent.html:11 ERROR Error: The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance. Check https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datetimepicker/integration-with-json/ for possible resolution.**
please help me out where i am doing mistake

Comment: Did you get an answer, maybe from Telerik support?